# As an overworked mother to a newborn baby, is it okay to miss a prayer and pray it later?

Tags: salat, salat-qada, baby

Now that I have given birth, I have to breastfeed and do many things as a mother, so I am not getting the time to finish that prayer.

Is it okay to leave that prayer, or I should finish it? By finish it I mean pray it as a missed prayer.

Comment: Dhuhr, Asr, and Isha are quite flexible in terms of when you can perform them. Fajr and Maghrib, for obvious reasons, have a smaller window. As a suggestion, if you have a smartphone, the ‘Athan Pro’ app really helps with planning.

Answer (score 1):

Prayer obligatory to perform within its stipulated time:

> “Verily, the prayer is enjoined on the believers at fixed hours”
>
> [an-Nisa 4:103]

Each prayer has a time range in which it can be performed, for example Fajr can be performed from sahr to shrook. If you delay prayer while remaining in its alloted time period it is permissible. However if you are asking about delaying it beyond its alloted time, then it is not permissible.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid that you still have to pray, pregnancy and the situation you have is not an excuse for delaying the prayers, but they are for delaying fasting Ramadan. You can repent for God to forgive you and ask God for help because God Almighty Says (interpretation of the meaning):

> ”So keep your duty to God and fear Him as much as you can” **[al-Taghaabun 64:16]**

In case you are not able to pray on ground, you can on chair. There’s a Hadith about that:

> It was narrated that ‘Imraan ibn Husayn (may God be pleased with him) said: “I was suffering from haemorrhoids and I asked the Prophet (peace and blessings of God be upon him) about praying. He said, ‘Pray standing, and if you cannot, then sitting down, and if you cannot, then lying on your side.’” **Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 1117.**

And the Prophet (peace and blessings of God be upon him) said:

> ”If I command you to do a thing, then do as much of it as you can.” **Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 7288; Muslim, 1337.**

Means, try your best not to miss the prayers. You’ll get rewarded.

> If a woman is about to give birth and she feels labour pains and starts to bleed, then that is the blood of nifaas, and she should stop praying and fasting.
>
> But if no blood appears, she should pray even if the cervix has started to dilate, and she should carry on praying until she gives birth.
>   <sub>Islam Q&A, [She did not pray during pregnancy out of ignorance](https://islamqa.info/en/142657)</sub>

God also Says:

> ”God burdens not a person beyond his scope” **[al-Baqarah 2:286]**

It means that it is a test from God. And if you have a tough situations, there’s a perfect Du’a for this:

> ”O You, the Alive, the Eternal! By Your mercy I’m pleading for rescue.”

And if God wish, you can make it. Sometimes, you have difficult times like this one you have, because God wants To test you, if you want to pass His test, you must ask His help because God Says:

> And your Lord says: "Call on Me; I will answer your (Prayer)
>
> - Quran, surah 40 (Ghafir), ayah 60[2]

And the most important thing is not to give up hope in your Du’a. I’m sure this time is the time when He tests you. Try to organize better your schedule, time and if God wishes everything will be ok. If you try your best to pray on time, God will be happy with you and you’ll be closer to Him because God Says:

> ”...The prayer is enjoined on the believers at fixed times”  [mawqootan].’

But you also must do many good deeds in order for you to get closer to your Lord. Oh and, remember this:

> ”A true champion will fight through anything.”
>
> ”A champion is someone who gets up, even when he can't.”

**References:**

https://islamqa.info/en/36738

https://islamqa.info/en/142657

Comment: This answer at least to 75% misses the actual topic of the question.

Comment: To be fair, the question was poorly written too; I edited it.